# How can a true Vector be implemented in Haskell?

Tags: data-structures, haskell, data-types

How could a true Vector type be implemented in Haskell? In order for something to be a Vector, it has to be stored sequentially in memory, with `O(1)` random access. But Haskell hides its memory management, and its datatypes describe trees! So how could you express that kind of requirement?

Comment: Use the mathematical definitions for true vectors. Here's a vector space library for you https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.7/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html

Comment: Where do those requirements for Vector come from? I know multiple definitions of the term 'vector' and only one of them has such requirements (C++'s `std::vector`).

Comment: To some extend in the same way as how to store a value in register in say C or C++, or you free memory in GC language - compiler is free to rearrange data, put the values in register etc. or expose the things by (extensions)[http://tinyurl.com/ovvxtqt]/(libraries)[http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.0] to programmers if they really need them - but assumption is that they don't care in most cases. In similar way Haskell programmers don't care in most cases if the data is packed in sequential region of memory instead of, for example eliminating the need for evaluation entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Not all data types in Haskell are trees. There are also the builtin types like functions or Int. Among those you find the type [Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html) which gives you O(1) access to its elements.

Some compilers, like GHC, also provide unboxed arrays. Those use less memory and per element access is faster, but that does not change the complexity of course.

On top of those arrays one can build data types similar to `std::vector` in C++. An example is the [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) library.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `Data.Vector.Unboxed` and `Data.Vector.Mutable` in the vector package:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector